# Laravel Eloquent - Get all records of child relation model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My data model is this:
Users > Offices > Organization

This is my model

```
class Organization extends Model  {

    protected $table = 'organizations';

    public function offices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Office');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->offices()->users();
    }
....
```

So.. I want to get all users from an organization (of all the offices).
But I don't know how to do something like

```
$this->offices()->users();
```

(Avoiding user a manual collection or map to do that)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, you have organization ID. You can load all users by using [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$users = User::whereHas('office', function ($q) use ($organizationId) {
        $q->where('organization_id', $organizationId);
    })
    ->get();
```

Make sure `office()` relationship is defined correctly in `User` model:

```
public function office()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Office');
}
```

Alternatively, you could define [`hasManyThrough()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Office', 'App\User');
}
```

And use it:

```
$organization->users()
```